# Modify layout of component options

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I'd like to style the component options page of my custom-developed component. I can see in the `Articles` com_config options there are coloured buttons for radio buttons and a nicer page layout (e.g. equal-width columns for labels and form fields). How can I customise this for my own component options screen within `com_config`?

Comment: Have you done anything to try and get the parameter value from com_config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your fields like this in the XML manifest file:

```
<field
  name="language"
  type="radio"
  class="btn-group"
  default="en"
  label="Language"
  description="What language do you want?">
<option
    value="en">English</option>
<option
    value="es">Spanish</option>
<option
    value="no">Norwegian</option>
</field>
```

For simple Yes/No buttons, try

```
<field
    name="intro"
    type="radio"
    class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
    default="1"
    label="Introduction"
    description="Show introduction?">
    <option
        value="1">JYES</option>
    <option
        value="0">JNO</option>
</field>
```

Comment: A-ha - `class` is not documented in http://docs.joomla.org/Radio_form_field_type. I saw the `btn-group-yesno` CSS classes in the Dev Tools but wasn't sure how to add. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Joomla 3, set `class="btn-group"` to your radio buttons, that should style them like the default Joomla radio buttons.